# Add breakpoint inside Mule Expression Component?

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

I'm learning to use the Mule Anypoint Studio software and things have been going okay so far.  I'm using the Debugger to learn a lot.  Right now I have an Expression Component with some looping inside of it and I'd like to be able to debug the code as it iterates through the looping inside of the Expression Component.  Is this possible?  I can't figure out how to get the debugger to dive inside of an Expression Component, if it's possible at all.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try step-in ? It take you inside of flow unless you reach up to smaller unit. You will able to evaluate expression and trace properties value but won't be able to take debug pointer till that point.

Comment: How do I try this?  I only see F8 to resume.  My code is in an Expression Component.  Thanks!

Comment: I might need to simulate similar case here

Comment: @Rashiki, It is not showing step-in stage for  components invoked for me too but same class and method invoked as Java component is available for debug.

Comment: Okay.  Thanks.  I'll have to think about using Java components going forward, then.  Thanks.